# Execute method On-Load of an object on a form in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

E.g. instead of having a button to initiate the method, the method automatically happens without any user interaction - automatically.

```
private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ServiceController sc = new ServiceController();
        sc.ServiceName = "Spooler";

        if (sc.Status.ToString().ToLower() == "stopped")
        {
            serviceStatusLabel.Text = "Installed but stopped";
        }

        if (sc.Status.ToString().ToLower() == "running")
        {
            serviceStatusLabel.Text = "Installed and started";
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        serviceStatusLabel.Text = "Service not installed";
    }
}
```

I just want the Label object to show the service status when the form is loaded up, without using a button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... Do I get your question correctly?
You want a piece of code to be executed when an object or the form is loaded?
Well that's easy :p

Click on your object (or form) in the designer, in the properties dock, click the lightning bolt icon, go to the *Load* or *Show* event, and double-click the box.
A new piece of code should now be created in the code view, something like this:

```
private void Object_Load(blabla) handles Object.Load
{
}
```

Whatever code is in that event will be executed when the object is loaded or shown.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see any "Load" or "Show" events in the events list

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Given your comment, are you actually after the [`Form.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx) event? It sounds like it. Any event handlers subscribed to that event will be executed "when the form is displayed for the first time".

(The confusing thing is that your title talks about "On-Load" *of an object* whereas it sounds like you really want the method to be called when the *form* is loaded.)

---

It's not really clear what you mean by "when its output on the form" but you might want to look at the [`TextChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx) and [`VisibleChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visiblechanged.aspx) events. That's if you want something to happen when the *label* is altered.

If you're looking for when the service *status* is altered, it doesn't look like there's an event raised for that, I'm afraid. Note that it would be *much* cleaner to switch on the enum value rather than to convert it to a string, lower it, and then compare that with hard-coded constants.

Comment: I just want the Label object to show the service status when the form is loaded up, without using a button

Comment: @Mike: So are you after the Form.Load event?

Comment: I think he means when the form is first shown, how to initialize the Text property automatically instead of in the click event of the button.

Comment: @Marcelo Hernández Rishmawy Yes thats what I meant

Comment: @Mike: See my edit then. It sounds like you *do* mean Form.Load.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a handler for the [Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx) event, it will run when the form gets loaded.